# Get the DisplayMember value of any object in ListBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox, and it's items consist of custom class objects (can be any class).

Then I set the DisplayMemberPath so the ListBox shows the right property of that custom class fine.

Now I need to enumerate the Items list of ListBox, and get the DisplayMember value of each item in the list, without knowing the type of the class in the list. Is there any way to get this DisplayMember value without Reflection?

Comment: Make your all custom class implemented by an interface

Comment: That would do for sure. I was wishing some generic solution, because I'm making a custom user control which has advanced text-search features for searching the values of combobox, and woudn't want to tie it to some interface. After all I think the way the ListBox shows the displaymember, is reflection after all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF, you don't need to implement an interface, or a base class for a container control to read the value of a property. In an ideal world, it would make sense to declare a base class or interface and have all of your custom classes extend, or implement these, but the benefit of that is really to keep your data type safe.

For example, in WPF, this is perfectly legal and will work just the same:

```
public class RadioButtonData
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class CustomData
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
private ObservableCollection<object> objects = new ObservableCollection<object>();
public ObservableCollection<object> Objects
{
    get { return objects; }
    set { objects = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Objects"); }
}
```

...

```
Objects.Add(new RadioButtonData() { Label = "Some Value" });
Objects.Add(new CustomData() { Label = "Another Value" });
```

...

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" DisplayMemberPath="Label" />
```

[image]

So as long as your various classes have the same name of property, then they will all be displayed in the same way, like above. They don't even have to be of the same type... just as long as the name matches that used in the `ListBox.DisplayMemberPath` property.

---

UPDATE >>>

Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question. In the case that you want to access these property values in code, then you have four basic options:

1. Define an Interface with a particular property and make your custom classes implement it.
2. Declare a base class with a particular property and make your custom classes extend it.
3. Create a (potentially long) section of `if else` statements that checks the type of each object and then accesses the relevant property.
4. Use reflection.

In my personal opinion, I would recommend options 1 or 2 first, then 4 and lastly 3. I'm really not sure what you have against reflection, but it's really not that bad, or slow... I'd certainly prefer to use it rather than having an `else if` statement for every possible type used.

Comment: The question was: if I go through these objects in for loop, for example, is there a way to get this displayed value: foreach (var obj in listbox.Items) { Console.WriteLine( obj.DisplayMember <-- how to do this without reflection? ); }

Comment: I can use reflection like this, but I was hoping for a solution that doesn't use reflection: foreach (var obj in listbox.Items) { 
Console.WriteLine( obj.GetType().GetProperty(listbox.DisplayMemberPath).GetValue(val, null).ToString()); }

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood your question then. Please see my answer update.

Comment: I love reflection, but not sure if it works with obfuscated assemblies? - great answer Sheridan